# C/C++ pattern: exiting a for() loop on elapsed timeout

Tags: c++

In embedded C/C++ programming is quite common to write for loops of this type:

```
...
 for(int16_t i=0; i<5; i++)
 {
    if(true == unlockSIM(simPinNumber))
       return true;
    wait_ms(1000);
 }
 return false;
 ...
```

or like this while() loop:

```
bool CGps::waitGpsFix(int8_t fixVal)
{
   int16_t iRunStatus=0, iFixStatus=0;
   _timeWaitGpsFix = CSysTick::instance().set(TIME_TO_WAIT_GPS);

   while(1)
   {
      bool bRet = _pGsm->GPSstatus(&iRunStatus, &iFixStatus);
      if( (true == bRet) && (1 == iRunStatus) && (iFixStatus >= fixVal) )
         return true;
      if(CSysTick::instance().isElapsed(_timeWaitGpsFix))
         return false;
      wait_ms(500);
   }
   return false;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

is there any well known good pattern useful to don't write each time so many lines but just a function or method call?

Comment: the whole `wait_ms`-pattern is a very, very, very bad pattern and you should avoid it like the plague

Comment: I've never understood why people feel the need to compare a Boolean variable to `true` or `false`.

Comment: presumably, the execute-around idiom would find a use here.

Comment: Conditional waits?

Answer (score 1):

For the for loop, you could use a function template that accepts the function (must return a boolean) and return when succeeded.  For the while loop, things get more complicated, but I guess that lambdas could be used as true and false conditions.

For loop:

```
#include <iostream>

template<int retries, int wait_time, typename FUNC, typename ...Args>
bool retry(FUNC& f, Args &&... args)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < retries; ++i)
    {
        if (f(std::forward<Args>(args)...)) return true;
        if (i < retries - 1)
        {
            std::cout << "waiting " << wait_time << "\n";
        }
    }
    return false;
}

bool func(int i)
{
    return (i > 0);
}

bool func2(int i, int j)
{
    return (i > j);
}

int main()
{

    bool result = retry<5, 500>(func, 0);
    std::cout << result << "\n";

    result = retry<5, 500>(func, 1);
    std::cout << result << "\n";

    result = retry<5, 500>(func2, 1, 2);
    std::cout << result << "\n";

    result = retry<5, 500>(func2, 1, 0);
    std::cout << result << "\n";
}
```

[See example in coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1ac9d23c8c9d194f)

Comment: What is gained by making `retries` and `wait_time` template arguments, instead of just regular function arguments?

Comment: Probably a little bit of time, but that doesn't matter because of the wait.  However, it defines the retry and then you pass the function and parameters, so that looks fine at least.

Comment: It seems like it might increase the binary size, though.

Comment: Yes, but the question was "what is gained?".  I would think that most normal size projects don't have more than 50 of these loops and the majority have similar retry parameters.

Comment: Guys, I put some abstractions in the code. In embedded programming when a RF communication is needed we assume it is not reliable so a simple retry mechanism is mandatory. Don't think to wait_ms(..) as a way to loose time, yes when there is no RTOS or no task switching mechanism it looses time but think to it as an abstraction as a way to suspend a task for n milliseconds.

Comment: Stefaanv: in RF communication management there are potentially many of these loops. Actually I am simplifying a project that uses too many loops and also done in little different variations. At the moment seems I can realize just 6-8 C++ methods containing one of the two loop type I posted but the methods will be called many times. Of course compared with actual solution it is a lot better.

Comment: @MassimoManca then perhaps take a look at [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/96a1e965b3ba2e4f). It's too similar for me to really want to submit it as a different answer, but it might help you find an optimal solution.

Comment: @jaggedSpire: actually, I would post it as an answer, it's a different approach requiring lambdas

Comment: @MassimoManca: you do realise that this approach is making your code less bloated than the original?  Even with all different retries and wait_times, it is not more bloated.  Even with the passed parameters (easy to change), chances are the compiler has inlined the code, leaving you with similar result.

Comment: @jaggedSpire: your solution also supports the while loop.

Comment: @stefaanv kind of--the await function I'm using waits *until* a certain amount of time has passed since the interval was instantiated. OP seems like that *might* not be possible for him, though he can just wait the total time every pass through his loop if he can tolerate drift.

Comment: @stefaanv posted.

Comment: To everybody: I am switching to C++11/14 just now because this time I can use GCC instead other vendors C++ embedded compilers conforming to C++03. In this context I am simplifying at my best a couple of modules with a lot bloated code. The first step was to reduce and isolated the loops I described in less space, than the idea was to ask for help because there are several option as templates, lambda functions and some variations. I am totally sure these solutions are better... I wanted to change the code from beginning, I don't like to have duplicate code, much better a template.

Comment: @MassimoManca can you give a version number?

Answer (score 1):

This is simple enough with the *execute-around idiom*, which executes a given piece of code in an environment/set of circumstances controlled by the function the piece of code is passed in to. Here, we'll simply be calling the piece of code in a loop once every *n* milliseconds, either for a set amount of time, or for a set number of times.

---

Since you're working in an embedded environment and seem to be using a set of timing mechanisms different from that provided by `<chrono>` and `<thread>`, I've tried to adjust my answer so you can use the methods you seem to have access to to do the same thing. These are the functions I've used in my solution:

```
// similar functions to what you seem to have access to
namespace timing{

    // interval defined as some arbitrary type

    interval getInterval(int msCount);

    bool intervalElapsed(interval i);

    void await(interval i);
}
```

<sup>A note on the `await` function there--it takes an interval, and pauses execution until the interval has passed. It seems like the closest you can get to this *might* be simply waiting for the total number of milliseconds instead, though that strategy will introduce a certain amount of drift in your timings. If you can tolerate that (and given you're using it, it seems you can), then great.</sup>

The retry-for variant would look like this, given the above function signatures:

```
template <typename Func>
bool pollRetries(
        int retryLimit, 
        int msInterval, 
        Func func){

    for(int i = 0; i < retryLimit; ++i){
        auto interval = timing::getInterval(msInterval);
        if (func()){return true;}
        timing::await(interval);
    }
    return false;
}
```

and the retry-while would look like this:

```
template <typename Func>
bool pollDuration(
        int msLimit, 
        int msInterval, 
        Func func){

    auto limit = timing::getInterval(msLimit);
    while(!timing::intervalElapsed(limit)){
        auto interval = timing::getInterval(msInterval);
        if (func()){return true;}
        timing::await(interval);
    }
    return false;
}
```

[*Live demo on Coliru*](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/96a1e965b3ba2e4f)

Both functions take a single functor which will be called with no arguments, and which returns either a boolean or something convertible to a boolean value. If the evaluation ever returns true, the loop will exit and the function will return true. Otherwise it'll return false at the end of the retry count or period.

Your sample code would convert to this:

retry for loop:

```
return pollRetries(5,1000,[simPinNumber](){
    return unlockSIM(simPinNumber);
});
```

retry while loop:

```
return pollDuration(TIME_TO_WAIT_GPS, 500, [fixVal, this](){
    int16_t 
        iRunStatus = 0,
        iFixStatus = 0;

    bool bRet = this->_pGsm->GPSstatus(&iRunStatus, &iFixStatus);
    return bRet && (1 == iRunStatus) && (iFixStatus >= fixVal);
});
```

You can pass either functors or function pointers into these methods and the execution will occur, so you can also simply directly pass in lambdas to be executed. A few notes about that:

1. Lambdas without a capture group can be converted to function pointers with the unary `+` operator, allowing the template to use the function pointer instantiation of the template rather than one based off the lambda. You might want to do this because:
2. Every lambda in every function has an anonymous type. Passing the lambda into the template function will result in an additional template instantiation which might increase binary size.
3. You can also mitigate the above problem by defining your own functor class for uses that share a set of persistent state.
4. You might try making the timing functions into variadic templates per @stefaanv's solution. If you went this route, you could remove the capture groups from your lambdas and pass that information in manually, which would allow you to convert the lambdas into function pointers as though they were stateless.
5. Were most of these retry loops for a single class you could simply define the retry mechanisms as member function templates, and then subject yourself to member function pointers, thereby passing state around using the called object. I'd not recommend this though, as member function pointers are a bit of a pain to deal with, and you could get the same result by making a stateless lambda take a reference to the object, and passing in `*this` to the call. You'd also have to define all the bits of code as their own functions, rather than simply defining them within the function where they were used.